# How to Implement Button dropdown component in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to create a button that opens a menu with the possibility to display multiple buttons.
([Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components/blazor-dropdown-menu#:%7E:text=The%20Blazor%20Dropdown%20Menu%20is,%2C%20RTL%2C%20and%20UI%20customization.))
I seem to not understand how the sample is implemented behind the scenes when the events are getting implemented... more details can be found here. ([How to Documentation](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/drop-down-menu/native-event/))

How did they implement this template and/or is there another way to implement a clean dropdown button component in Blazor without using the syncfusion library?

To make it clear; I'm not looking for a way to implement the syncfusion library.

---

Current progress:

**Dropdown menu**

```
<div class="more-options-menu-button">
<button @onclick="OnShowMenuClick" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
    <svg height="24px" width="24px">
        <image href=@MoreOptionsIconUrl height="24px" width="24px"></image>
    </svg>
</button>
@if (Display)
{
    <section class="menu" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
        @MenuOptions
    </section>
}
</div>
@code {
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment MenuOptions { get; set; }

private bool Display { get; set; }

private const string MoreOptionsIconUrl = "https://localhost:5001/svg/general/more_vert_24dp.svg";

public void Hide()
{
    this.Display = false;
}

public void OnShowMenuClick()
{
    this.Display = !this.Display;
}
}
```

**MenuOption**

```
<button id="Id" @onclick="OnClick">
@Title
</button>

@code {
[Parameter]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**How to use**

```
 <OptionsMenuComponent>
            <MenuOptions>
                <MenuOptionComponent Id="remove" Title="Remove" OnClick="Remove" />
            </MenuOptions>
        </OptionsMenuComponent>

@code {
   private void Remove()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Removing...");
}
}
```

The issue now is; when the menu is open you can't close it when you click on a menu option button and you can't close it when you click outside of the menu when the menu is open.

How can you close the component from outside the component?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a blazor component e.g MyDropdownButton

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    @Title
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    @ChildContent        
</div>
```

```
@code {
[Parameter]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }    }
```

You can pass parameter for the button title. I am creting an wrapper for boostrap Dropdowns.

The @ChildContent is where will render the other component that you will create e.g MyDropdownButtonItem where will be list of items

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="@Href">@ActionName</a>
 @code {
[Parameter]
public string Href { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string ActionName { get; set; }    }
```

Finally You will use it like this

```
<MyDropdownButton Title="title">
<MyDropdownButtonItem Href="#" ActionName="actionName" />
MyDropdownButtonItem Href="#" ActionName="actionName2" />
</MyDropdownButton>
```

Comment: I agree this works, but only for redirects to other URLs... How can you bind events like onclick events which are passed down from the parent component?

Comment: You can pass event as parameter.   [Parameter]   public EventCallback onclickEvent { get; set; } if you want to handle it on child.

Comment: This works, but I'm still struggling with how to close the dropdown menu-onclick or when clicked outside the component. I've added my current solution in the question.

Comment: @JakeL it feels like you want us to do all the work ? please open a new question or research further.

Comment: To be fair the code I've pasted I got already before posting the question. I could've posted that from the start but I would prefer to understand the build up from syncfusion because the current code seems like a deadlock to me.

Comment: if you change your question after receiving answers is hard to get more answers, people will pass, see the current ones and will not read this comments. my advice post a new question with a link to this one.