# Blazor how to add outside-component events to a component?

Tags: blazor

I'm creating a dropdown menu button in Blazor.
The things I want the component to do is:

1. Add buttons to the dropdown menu component
2. The addable buttons in the menu need to be onclick-bindable
3. The dropdown menu button onclick should open/close the menu
4. When the menu is open and you press outside the component the menu needs to be closed

My current code:

**Dropdown menu**

```
<div class="more-options-menu-button">
<button @onclick="OnShowMenuClick" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
    <svg height="24px" width="24px">
        <image href=@MoreOptionsIconUrl height="24px" width="24px"></image>
    </svg>
</button>
@if (Display)
{
    <section class="menu" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
        @MenuOptions
    </section>
}
</div>
@code {
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment MenuOptions { get; set; }

private bool Display { get; set; }

private const string MoreOptionsIconUrl = "https://localhost:5001/svg/general/more_vert_24dp.svg";

public void Hide()
{
    this.Display = false;
}

public void OnShowMenuClick()
{
    this.Display = !this.Display;
}
}
```

**MenuOption**

```
<button id="Id" @onclick="OnClick">
@Title
</button>

@code {
[Parameter]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**How to use**

```
 <OptionsMenuComponent>
            <MenuOptions>
                <MenuOptionComponent Id="remove" Title="Remove" OnClick="Remove" />
            </MenuOptions>
        </OptionsMenuComponent>

@code {
   private void Remove()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Removing...");
}
}
```

I can do with the above code everything except 4 (close menu when click on outside component).

How can I handle this event when it is not related to the scoped component?

Note: I found a [Library](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/drop-down-menu/native-event/) which seems to handle every requirement I need but I'm not certain how they created the related component.

This question was already asked in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584219/how-to-implement-button-dropdown-component-in-blazor/68587362?noredirect=1#comment121223618_68587362), but I was advised to create a new dedicated issue.

Comment: I do not believe it would be possible for your component to automatically get an event when user clicked outside the div.  Best I can think of is to use the mouseout event.  In this way when the mouse leaves the component you could do something in your component (for example close the menu or trigger a timer to close the menu after some time period).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the onfocusout event? [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

In your OptionsMenuComponent you can try this to see how it works:

```
<div class="more-options-menu-button">
<button @onclick="OnShowMenuClick" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" @onfocusout="Hide">
    <svg height="24px" width="24px">
        <image href=@MoreOptionsIconUrl height="24px" width="24px"></image>
    </svg>
</button>
@if (Display)
{
    <section class="menu" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
        @MenuOptions
    </section>
}
```

Comment: Focus doesn't seem to work because I'm trying to do it on an div and not on an input/focusable element. If I put the onfocusout like in your example the event which is clicked from within the menu is not triggered as well.

Comment: You can add `tabindex="0"` to the div to make it focusable and then onfocusout works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @onfoucsout.

When the button is clicked, it is focused. So therefore, on the button if you give it a @onfoucsout attribute and call the function or method that toggles the drop down list.

For example:

```
<button onClick="@ToggleDropDownMenu())" @onfocusout="@(() => ToggleDropDownMenu())">
  <div hidden="@(!_isMenuVisible)>
  @MenuOptions
</div>
```

In your razor file:

```
private bool _isMenuVisible = false;

private void ToggleDropDownMenu()
{
    _isMenuVisible = !_isMenuVisible;
}
```